# SQL Server stored procedure with more than 1 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, rdbms

I am unable to create a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Calculate the total of students to summation of Mark1, Mark2 and Mark3 and update for student whose city is Chennai using a stored procedure.
In the same procedure, add a new column `AvgMark` in `StudentMarks` table and calculate average for all students.

This is what I have tried so far

```
create or alter procedure TotMarks
as 
begin
    update StudentMarks 
    set Total = Mark1 + Mark2 + Mark3 
    from StudentMarks 
    join CityMaster on StudentMarks.CityID = CityMaster.CityID 
    where CityName = 'Chennai' 

    alter table StudentMarks 
        add AvgMark decimal default Total/3
end
```

I am getting this error and I don't know why.

> The name "Total" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions
> are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables.
> Column names are not permitted.

And I created a null column `Total` in `StudentMarks` while creating the table, so no need to create that column in the stored procedure to update the summation of Mark1, Mark2 and Mark3.

Comment: "add a new column "AvgMark" in StudentMarks tables and calculate average for all students" odd thing to do in a procedure. That's the type of thing that is only done once. Perhaps you actually just want to *calculate* it in a `SELECT` query. This would make more sense, as it means you don't need to store the same data twice.

Comment: @Zoro, Add a column in your table called AvgMark and using cursor you can calculate each row wise and update the average marks in that AvgColumn.
[You can go through this tutorials]
(https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-cursor/)

Comment: If I am know wrong what you want is set the default value of AvgMark. Or you want it to be Total/3 all the time?

Comment: @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur all the time

Comment: @Charlieface, i thought the same. but this is a task given to me by my trainer. unfortunately he is not available now to ask this doubt.

Comment: I too don't follow why you want to add the column in the procedure. What do you suppose would happen here the second time you execute the procedure? What would you expect/want to occur? Are you `DROP`ing the column again elsewhere? If so, why are you constantly `ADD`ing and `DROP`ing a column?

Comment: Also, might as well mention that having 3 `Mark` columns infers a denormalisation issue; what happens when someone only has 2 marks? What happens when someone needs a 4th?

Comment: If one person downvoted it doesn't really matter, it's not a reflection on you rather on the question and whether it's worth keeping around. As I asked: what exactly are you trying to do? Why are you adding and dropping columns? We can't ask your trainer, only you can. We don't know why you were set this question, and if you don't even understand what the question is, we certainly don't. So we can't help you until we get more explanation what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to save Total/3 in AvgMark:

```
create or alter procedure TotMarks
as 
begin
update StudentMarks set Total=coalesce(Mark1,0)+coalesce(Mark2,0)+coalesce(Mark3,0) from StudentMarks join CityMaster on StudentMarks.CityID=CityMaster.CityID WHERE CityName='Chennai' 
alter table StudentMarks add AvgMark as Total/3
end
```

Comment: I did as you said. No error was show. The sp got executed successfully. I used select statement to display all the columns in StudentMarks table....both the columns 'Total' and 'Avgmark' are empty( null)@kazi mohammadali nur

Comment: Please execute following query to check which rows would be updated `select * from from StudentMarks join CityMaster on StudentMarks.CityID=CityMaster.CityID WHERE CityName='Chennai'`

Comment: 100 Priyanka 15 1000 56.0 89.0 70.0 NULL 2022-08-21 23:02:09.363 NULL 1000 Chennai 2022-08-21 22:54:28.033  -------this is the result i got. unfortunately i am unable to display column name here. you can see there are two null values where first one corresponds to  column 'Total' and second corresponds to column 'AvgMark'......why? both of the columns are not getting updated....why?? Thanks for Your help though. @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur

Comment: Please check if Mark1, Mark2 or Mark3 is null. If any one of three is null then the summation will be null.

Comment: @Zoro I have revised my answer. If there is any null value it will calculate properly.